# Force.com IDE eclipse missing Apex Test Runner pane and Execute Anonymous pane

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

While using Force.com IDE, I closed the "Apex Test Runner" and "Execute Anonymous" pane by mistake.  They are usually right next to the Problems pane (see attached image).  Does anyone know how to get them back? I am looking all over the menu options but no luck in finding the solution.  I am using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 version with Force.com IDE version 30.0.0.201404021749.

[image: Force.com IDE missing panes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, assuming you have the Force.com perspective selected in the top right, is to select Window -> Reset Perspective.

Otherwise you can use Window -> Show View and use the search field to find the views by name and open them one by one. (And add any other views that are not part of the default perspective views.)

Answer (score 0):

See this - [Force.com IDE 35.0.0.201510211056 in Eclipse missing run test class option](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98177/force-com-ide-35-0-0-201510211056-in-eclipse-missing-run-test-class-option)
- sad but true - also notice to select specific class otherwise you'll be running all ..

Comment: User1786607 would you mind at least including the relevant information in your answer ? URLs may go dead after a while and render your answer meaningless if no information is provided here.