# Force.com IDE 35.0.0.201510211056 in Eclipse missing run test class option

Tags: force.com-ide

Force.com IDE 35.0.0.201510211056 and Force.com IDE Debugger 35.0.0.201510211056 in eclipse but it doesn't show this option to run test class, is their any way i can see it because it show the Apex_Test_Result panel but running a test class option is missing. plz help

Comment: Have a look into this link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.eclipse.meta/eclipse/runTests.htm It may help you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With Winter 16 (API 35), the Force.com IDE began providing "run configurations for Apex tests, with configurable logging levels". See the [Force.com IDE Release Notes](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Release_Notes) for details on this feature and how to configure them. Once you have them configured, you press a green arrow in the menu panel above to run your selected test class (outlined in red). See graphic below.

[image: Eclipse Screen Shot]

Comment: It looks like we need to configure for every test class every time with this new feature unless you want to run all tests. Is there anything that you could suggest to do some handy configuration and run test for a single class with a single click?

Comment: Yup! That is exactly what I am doing right now!

Comment: Nice, it's actually pretty sweet, and it looks like it shows line coverage in the IDE now too.