# How can I create test class in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: force.com, force.com-ide

I am trying to create test class using force.com IDE. I cannot find the picklist of selecting type of apex class- test class.I created that class in my org and fetched it on eclipse. but I also not getting option to run test. (Previously I was getting it.) Can anyone tell me what should I do? I have also upgraded force.com IDE to spring 16.Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using Latest version of Eclipse (Mars), In this version some options have been changed for test class

For create a test class: Create an apex class and put @isTest on the top
Now write your test class code/methods.

How to run : Select test class from Package explorer| Right click | Run As | Run Configurations..
In the pop up select your project , class and test method then click on Run

Now you will be able to check code coverage/Errors

Thanks

Comment: The thing is not in Eclipse but in Force.com plugin. Other information is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods), [Add a Test Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm) and [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm).

In short. There is no special type *Test Class*. You just create a Class. One thing you can do, is to select a test template, while creating a class. Test Class must be annotated as @isTest as each test method.

```
@isTest
private class MyTest {
    @isTest
    static void myTest() {
       // Add test method logic using System.assert(), System.assertEquals()
       // and System.assertNotEquals() here.
     }    
}
```

You might want to check [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) for new features of Force.com plugin.

[How to run test(s) in Eclipse](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98177/force-com-ide-35-0-0-201510211056-in-eclipse-missing-run-test-class-option).