# How to run a single test class in Force.com IDE 36.0.0.201601221512 on Mac OS X

Tags: apex, unit-test, force.com-ide

When i do a right click on a test class in Force.com IDE then i don't see the option that runs the tests. In previous versions it was possible to run tests of a single test class that way. Does anyone know how to get this option back? I am running Force.com IDE on a Mac.

[image: missing run test option]

There is already another [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98177/force-com-ide-35-0-0-201510211056-in-eclipse-missing-run-test-class-option) regarding this topic. The Answer points to the Force.com IDE Release notes but i can't find any information on how to get this right click option back. Since i have more than 30 test classes creating a run configuration for each would mess the run interface up. This is why i would like to have the right click option back.

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. go to Run Configurations...
2. Select Apex test
3. Create new, give a name
4. Select Force.com project
5. Enable logging if needed
6. Go to Test subtab, select test class by name

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This would mean i need to create a run configuration for every test class i have. Since i have many test classes i would rather right click the class and run as test. Is there any way to get this option back?

Comment: Only downgrading Force.com API version. For me this approach also seems a bit long, but for example you can run only test methods you need instead of commenting unwanted ones to save execution time.

Comment: oh what a pity. I don't get why they removed this option. Thx.